# How to reuse logic for class instantiation and get around IllegalAccessException?

Tags: java, lambda, reflection

**Goal:** create a util class that will contain some reflection code, in particular code that creates a new class instance. That code is not very simple, so I want to keep it in a util function so that I can reuse it multiple times.

**Approach/Idea:** create `ClassUtil` that will have a function that returns a lambda that creates a new class instance. I will execute that lambda in `MyClassFactory`, a class that I know can create a new instance of `MyClassOne` because it will be in the same package and the default constructor is `package-private` access modifier, so `ClassUtil` cannot make an instance of that class, but since I am executing the lambda in a class that can all should be good.

**Error:**

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.util.ClassUtil cannot access a member of class com.somepackage.MyClassOne with modifiers ""

**Question:** How to make Java runtime think that it is `MyClassFactory` the one that is trying the instantiation?

**UML:**

[image]

**Code:**

```java
package com.somepackage

import com.util.ClassUtil;

public class MyClassFactory {
    public MyClass createMyClass() {
        String implClassFQN = <get impl class FQN from somewhere>;
        return (MyClass ) ClassUtil.createClassInstance().apply(implClassFQN);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.util;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class ClassUtil {
    /**
     * @return a new instance of the class given the class fully qualified name
     */
    public static Function<String, Object> createClassInstance() {
        return (classFQN) -> {
            try {
                return Class.forName(classFQN).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Impl class specified in properties file not found", e);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Default constructor not found", e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Workaround/New Approach:** would anyone know how I could have taken a different approach to achieve the same goal?

**Note:** If I put the code from `ClassUtil` into `MyClassFactory` it works fine, but I want it reusable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question literally, there is a [class capable of encapsulating an access context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html) that can be passed to another method to perform actions with it without the need for access override, assuming that the caller has enough trust in the invoked method.

Unlike access override, this will work even in restricted environments, e.g. with an installed security manager or when the access would cross module boundaries. Also, the class lookup is performed as-if happening in the caller’s code which can be relevant when the two packages belong to different class loaders.

```
package com.somepackage;

import com.util.ClassUtil;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;

public class MyClassFactory {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass obj = new MyClassFactory().createMyClass();
        System.out.println("created "+obj);
    }
    public MyClass createMyClass() {
        String implClassFQN = MyClassFactory.class.getName()+"$MyClass";
        return (MyClass)ClassUtil.createClassInstance(MethodHandles.lookup())
            .apply(implClassFQN);
    }
    private static class MyClass { // normally inaccessible by com.util.ClassUtil

    }
}
```

```
package com.util;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class ClassUtil {
    /**
     * @return a new instance of the class given the class fully qualified name
     */
    public static Function<String, Object>
        createClassInstance(MethodHandles.Lookup context) {

        return name -> {
            try {
                return context.findConstructor(context.findClass(name),
                    MethodType.methodType(void.class)).invoke();
            } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Impl class specified in properties file not found", e);
            } catch(NoSuchMethodException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Default constructor not found", e);
            } catch(RuntimeException | Error e) {
                throw e;
            } catch(Throwable e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```
created com.somepackage.MyClassFactory$MyClass@4783da3f
```

Comment: thank you @Holger, `MethodHandles` is something I did not see before, although it is there for quite some time. I couldn't find a useful resource by searching the web, most of them just compare it to _reflection_ or _lambdametafactory_ and do some pros and cons, but don't say when to use which, what use-case suits each best. Clearly there is overlap in capability, so there must be a best scenario for each.

I'll get a recent book and do my own analysis when I get some time. If you have any recommendations I am all ears :)

Comment: This solves the problem in the _Title_ of the question AND the "in-line" question asked within the question body.
> How to make Java runtime think that it is MyClassFactory the one that is trying the instantiation?
Therefore accepting this one.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the constructor accessible via:

[AccessibleObject#setAccessible(true)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject[],%20boolean))

```
public static Function<String, Object> createClassInstance() {
    return (classFQN) -> {
        try {
            Constructor<?> constructor = Class.forName(classFQN).getDeclaredConstructor();
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            return constructor.newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Impl class specified in properties file not found", e);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Default constructor not found", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I got way too much into the mindset of tricking Java it thinks a different class made the instantiation, that I did not even think about a simple solution like yours @PSandro to just ignore access modifiers :)
Thank you very much for such a quick answer!